# Highstock can use {point.tt}, but Highcharts can not , why?

Tags: highcharts

I am switching from Highstock to highcharts, but met some error.

My point is as {x:11, y:22, tt:'xx'}, tt is defined by myself which I wanna show in the header of tooltip. But the header doesn't show in Highcharts.

my example is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodouwang/cwm3pcuq/1/) , HighStock is OK, but Highcharts failed to show the header.

```
$(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
  //var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'USD',
        data: [{
          x: 86400000 * 6,
          y: 3,
          tt: 'xx'
        }]
      }],
      plotOptions: {
        line: {
          tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.tt}</span><br/>',
          }
        },
      }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is a datetime axis feature. In Highstock, if an axis type is datetime method for processing headerFormat is wrapper (extended). Also, that wrap comes from the highstock file, in the highcharts is not present.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwm3pcuq/2/

If you use a different kind of axis you can build the tooltip with the formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter.